# Fresh install /usr/share/X11/xkb/ folder online?

Tags: keyboard-layout, default

I made a few changes in my /usr/share/X11/xkb/ folder to deal with a troublesome keyboard, I am now getting a new keyboard and want to completely reset this folder back to the defaults that were on my PC when ubuntu was freshly installed. Where do I find a copy of this folder?

Comment: What kind of changes did you make? can you not overwrite them by reinstalling the `xkb-data` package?

Comment: @steeldriver all I did was rebind a few keys that don't get used to ones that do need to be used but aren't actually on my keyboard, I don't know how to reinstall the xkb-data either if u could tell me how to do that it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only edited pre-existing files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/` (rather than adding new files), then I *think* it should be sufficient to re-install the `xkb-data` package - either using the Software application, or from the command line

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data
```

If you still believe you need to find a copy online, then you can search by package name at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) and select the appropriate package for your version from there.